# What to write about testing my application?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, documentation, testcase

I'm doing an academic project and I'm not asking for help, only suggestions for content when it comes to testing:

Basically I have made a game, and I've been advised to AVOID writing about low level testing and just put a brief section dedicated to testing. But what on earth do I include? My game is quite complex so maybe just a test case table for the main functions saying they work correctly? If so, isn't testing about TRYING to crash the software?

Of course I've tested my application frequently as a built it, but there was no real structure. If I'm to fill just a single page or 2 on high level testing, what would people suggest? I have to put something in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all depends on the kind of project. If you are writing from a scientific point of view, that is, your program was designed to show the feasibility of some theory or to yield numerical results, a single paragraph about the presence of testing and a table of the tested aspects suffices.

If you are writing from an engineering POV (say, a thesis in an engineering-oriented CS course), you should just write about your methods: How did you select test cases? Did you perform unit testing, system testing or both? Are the tests automated and portable? In short, discuss your approach from a software engineering POV, give a brief overview over what happened, and then show that you learned your trade by discussing the merits, shortcomings and experiences of this process.

Answer (score 1):

I expect they mainly want you demonstrate some kind of systematic approach to testing. They probably don't expect you to have the expertise used in commercial software testing.

One basic thing you can do is to write a test script - basically a checklist of steps covering a variety of situations within the game. You should test the 'happy path', i.e. the normal successful way of playing, the game, and also any 'alternative paths', where you try something unexpected, and verify the system behaves correctly. In a game this could be something like trying to make your character walk through a wall.

Comment: Thanks, sorry by 'script' you simply mean a list of things to check and not something I should be parsing with an interpreter right? :)

Comment: It can be automated, but you probably don't need to, so yes, just a list.

Answer (score 1):

Testing isn't just about trying to crash the software: that's relatively easy to test: just go through all your decision structures (if's else's cases' etc). 
Testing is really about 'does the application do what it's designed to do?'
For a game, that means you might take the various roles of user (game player, game reviewer, game configurator) and working through scenarios. List your 'game objective', 'way to interact' and 'expected results'. In 'expected results', you'd list both technical and user-interface results. Talking about scenarios gives you an idea of what you should be testing. In the 'game player' role, you might further subdivided it into 'casual users', 'expert user'. These are just some starting points for thinking about testing design: there's a heap on web about testing philosophies: use this resource. 
Someone who does this for a living will probably give you better advice, but this is just for starters...good luck!